# How to get data form `request.form` in Flask?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I am trying to get data from the request, I tried below-mentioned methods, I got `None` or `{}`.
Here is what I tried,

```
request.form['text']
request.form.get('text')
request.form.to_dict()
request.form.getlist('text[]')
request.form.getlist('text')
```

I am sending `json` data using apid clies (Advanced Rest Client).
Here is the data sample,

```
 [{
    "from": "971559xxxxxx",
    "id": "ABEGkZiAOQVVxxxxxxxxxxxxqEZ7KVtbxxxxx",
    "profile": {
        "name": "John Doe"
    },
    "text": {
        "body": "hi"
    },
    "timestamp": "1562080688",
    "type": "text",
    "to_number": "+971xxxxxxx"
    }]
```

Comment: Please explain how you are sending this data, and show the rest of your function.

Comment: Provide more of your code. What  do you mean by sample data? Is it a `JSON` response?

Comment: @KostasCharitidis, Sending as Json data.

Comment: @Reznik, I know its duplicate question, and I tried almost all the methods, but still facing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If it send a json you can get it from

`print(request.json)` or `print(request.get_json())`